# Преобразовать строку (со структурой похожей на массив) в обычный многомерный массив

Tags: php

Можно ли такую строку:

```
[['name' => 'id'], ['type' => 'INT(12)'], ['null' => true], ['prim' => true]],
[['name' => 'test'], ['type' => 'VARCHAR(15)'], ['null' => false], ['prim' => true]]
```

Преобразовать в обыкновенный массив? Если можно, то как это сделать как можно проще и желательно без парсинга?

Comment: Без парсинга - никак.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$raw = '['.
    preg_replace(array("/\[([^[{])/","/([^}])\]/"),array("{ $1","$1 }"),
        str_replace(array("=>","'"),array(":",'"'),$input)
        ).
    ']';

$output = json_decode(
    $raw,
    true
);
```

http://ideone.com/E69IOY

Не сохраняя лишней вложенности

```
$raw = str_replace(array("[[","]]","=>","'","[","]"),array("{","}",":",'"',"",""),$input);

$output = json_decode('['.$raw.']',true);
```

http://ideone.com/su8fOm

Comment: Строго говоря, json еще и одинарные кавычки содержать не должен

Comment: @АлексейШиманский таки добил, хотя ideone мне в этом препятствовал как мог

Comment: @rjhdby , замечательно , просто супер

Answer (score 1):

`Eval` не очень хорошо, но как вариант:

```
$str = "[['name' => 'test'], ['type' => 'VARCHAR(15)'], ['null' => false], ['prim' => true]],[['name' => 'test'], ['type' => 'VARCHAR(15)'], ['null' => false], ['prim' => true]]";

$str = "[".$str."]";

$array = [];

eval('$array='.$str.';');

print_r($array);
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/106dfcaf578a284cc1f63f27287d320835492d7f

Comment: а почему `Eval` не хорошо, работает ведь просто классно?

Comment: Ну смотря как использовать конечно, ну и поддерживать такой код сложнее, в общем лучше не увлекаться. А про опасности можно на просторах интернета почитать.

Comment: @perfect Замените первую строку на "[['name' => 'test'], ['type' => 'VARCHAR(15)'], ['null' => false], ['prim' => true]],[['name' => 'test'], ['type' => 'VARCHAR(15)'], ['null' => false], ['prim' => true]], phpinfo()"; и узнаете почему :)

Comment: Да, @Firepro прав, суть в том что если вы не уверены в данных которые попадут в eval, то обрабатывайте их пока не будите уверены, или не пихайте в eval

Comment: @Firepro , примерно догадываюсь что произойдет, в песочнице `phpinfo` отключена, посмотреть возможности нет.

Comment: @Bookin , учту , может позже найду что то получше

Answer (score 1):

Пример основанный на ответе от **rjhdby**, но уменьшая вложенность массива.

```
$str = "[['name' => 'test'], ['type' => 'VARCHAR(15)'], ['null' => false], ['prim' => true]],[['name' => 'test'], ['type' => 'VARCHAR(15)'], ['null' => false], ['prim' => true]]";

$result = preg_replace("/\[(.*?)\]/", "$1", $str);
$result = str_replace(["[","=>","'","]"],["{",":",'"',"}"],$result);
$result = "[".$result."]";

var_dump(json_decode($result, true));
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fe62117607fcee8ad2e5c0a8961e70199b3441d6

Comment: да приятней глазу и регулярки покороче, плюсанул, но пусть первенство за rjhdby останется он первоткрыватель, хотя я ваш вариант буду использовать.

Comment: @perfect Ну так тоj можно еще проще, `$raw = '['.str_replace(array("[[","]]","=>","'","[","]"),array("{","}",":",'"',"",""),$input).']';`, даже без регулярок ;) Добавил в ответ

Comment: @rjhdby , ух ты, еще лучше